# Migrating to AndroidX - android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS

Tags: android

I facing this issue while migrating from java to kotlin or android to androidx,here is my errror

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority androidx.multidex.provider
```

> 2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.b(FileProvider.java:606)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.a(FileProvider.java:579)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.a(FileProvider.java:417)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at com.prodege.answer.ui.surveyWebView.SurveysWebViewActivity.openCamera(SurveysWebViewActivity.kt:379)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at com.prodege.answer.ui.surveyWebView.SurveysWebViewActivity.access$openCamera(SurveysWebViewActivity.kt:33)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at com.prodege.answer.ui.surveyWebView.SurveysWebViewActivity$loadWebView$2.onShowFileChooser(SurveysWebViewActivity.kt:175)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at xl.a(PG:537)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at agE.runFileChooser(PG:72)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.494 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.495 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.495 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.495 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.495 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.495 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   2019-10-05 21:52:23.495 14821-14821/com.prodege.answer W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

here is my manifest file and i also extend multiDexApp

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.prodege.answer.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

here is my buil.gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.prodege.answer"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "2.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        //  buildConfigField "boolean", "URBAN_AIRSHIP_DEBUG_MODE", "false"
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        //  buildConfigField "boolean", "URBAN_AIRSHIP_DEBUG_MODE", "true"
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

kapt {
    javacOptions {
        // Increase the max count of errors from annotation processors.
        // Default is 100.
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 1000)
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}
```

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
//Kotlin support dependencies
implementation kotlinDependencies.core
implementation kotlinDependencies.coroutinesCore
implementation kotlinDependencies.coroutinesAndroid

// Kotlin Extension for Simplified coding
implementation androidxDependencies.ktx

//Android x design and backward compatibility support dependencies
implementation androidxDependencies.appCompat
implementation androidxDependencies.constraintlayout
implementation androidxDependencies.lifecycleExtention
implementation androidxDependencies.recyclerView
implementation androidxDependencies.multiDex
implementation androidxDependencies.roomRuntime
kapt androidxDependencies.roomCompiler


//Google dependencies
implementation googleDependencies.material
implementation googleDependencies.gson

// Network Library Retrofit dependencies
implementation networkDependencies.retrofit
implementation networkDependencies.retrofitGsonConveter
implementation networkDependencies.scalarConveter
implementation networkDependencies.okHttpLogs
implementation networkDependencies.kotlinCoroutineAdapterFactory
/* UI Related Dependencies */
implementation uiDependencies.glide
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'

/* Koin DI */
implementation kotlinDI.core
implementation kotlinDI.scope
implementation kotlinDI.viewModel


implementation analyticsSdk.adjust

implementation(name: 'fraudforce-lib-release-3.1.0', ext: 'aar')
implementation project(path: ':library')

implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'



// Testing Dependencies
androidTestImplementation androidxTestingDependencies.archCore
androidTestImplementation androidxTestingDependencies.core
androidTestImplementation androidxTestingDependencies.contrib
androidTestImplementation androidxTestingDependencies.intents
androidTestImplementation androidxTestingDependencies.uiAutoMator

//UA Dependencies
implementation uaFirebase.core
implementation uaFirebase.firebaseDynamicLink
implementation uaFirebase.firebaseMsg
implementation uaFirebase.urbanairship
implementation(uaFirebase.crashlytics)
{
    transitive = true
}
testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"

//sense360
implementation sense360Dep.sense360

//Cuebiq
/*implementation(cuebiqDep.cuebiq) {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
    exclude module: 'okio'
    exclude module: 'play-services-location'
    exclude module: 'gson'
}*/

//gimbal
implementation gimbalDep.gimbalSdk
implementation gimbalDep.gimbalImpl

implementation(gmsPlayServices.location) {
    force = true
}

implementation gmsPlayServices.gmsServicesAds
implementation gmsPlayServices.goodleMap
implementation gmsPlayServices.goodleMapUtil

implementation(gmsPlayServices.gmsServices) {
    force = true
}

implementation 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
/* BlinkReceipt dependencies*/
implementation project(':LibBlinkReceipt')
implementation "com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.0.9"
implementation blinkReceiptDependencies.retrofitscalers
implementation blinkReceiptDependencies.okio
implementation blinkReceiptDependencies.easyPermission
```

}

Comment: Could you please post your `build.gradle` file app-level too? And does `com.prodege.answer` match what you defined as `applicationId` in the same manifest file too?

Comment: Done please see

Answer (score 0):

```
import androidx.multidex.BuildConfig // NOT DO THIS!!!

val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+ ".provider", _tempFile)
```

**Do not use androidx.multidex.BuildConfig, Because this values are not the values of your application:**

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package androidx.multidex;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "androidx.multidex";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "release";
    public static final String FLAVOR = "";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = -1;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "";

    public BuildConfig() {
    }
}
```